# Jasper Report Error: ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number with name "" too small ORA-22924: snapshot too old

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jasper-reports

When I use Jasper as an interface, sometimes the interface invoke jasper and generate a report, then we got the exception as follows:

```
================================================================================
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: 
    Hibernate operation: Could not execute JDBC batch update; 
    uncategorized SQLException for SQL [update JIRepositoryCache set data=?, version=?, version_date=?, item_reference=? where id=?]; 
SQL state [72000]; 
error code [1555]; ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number  with name "" too small
ORA-22924: snapshot too old

; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number  with name "" too small


ORA-22924: snapshot too old



    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:83)

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)

    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertJdbcAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:424)

    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:410)

    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:424)

    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)

    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(HibernateTemplate.java:1055)

    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(HibernateTemplate.java:1048)

    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.service.impl.hibernate.HibernateRepositoryCache.getCachedItem(HibernateRepositoryCache.java:126)

    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.service.impl.hibernate.HibernateRepositoryCache.getCachedItem(HibernateRepositoryCache.java:99)

    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.service.impl.hibernate.HibernateRepositoryCache.cache(HibernateRepositoryCache.java:67)

    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor556.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)

    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)

    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)

    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)

    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)

    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.common.util.spring.ReattemptMethodInterceptor.invoke(ReattemptMethodInterceptor.java:51)

    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)

    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)

    at $Proxy16.cache(Unknown Source)

    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.multipleTenancy.PathTransformationRepositoryCache.cache(PathTransformationRepositoryCache.java:52)

    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.getCompiledReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:897)

    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.getJasperReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:659)

    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:369)

    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.executeReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:872)

    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.domain.impl.ReportUnitRequest.execute(ReportUnitRequest.java:57)

    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.execute(EngineServiceImpl.java:319)

    at com.jaspersoft.ji.engine.ProEngineServiceImpl.execute(ProEngineServiceImpl.java:132)

    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJob.executeReport(ReportExecutionJob.java:494)

    at com.jaspersoft.ji.report.options.engine.ReportOptionsExecutionJob.executeReport(ReportOptionsExecutionJob.java:103)

    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJob.executeAndSendReport(ReportExecutionJob.java:422)

    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJob.execute(ReportExecutionJob.java:231)

    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:195)

    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)

Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number  with name "" too small

ORA-22924: snapshot too old



    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:343)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10698)

    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)

    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeBatch(DelegatingStatement.java:297)

    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)

    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)

    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:266)

    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:168)

    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:322)

    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)

    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1028)

    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.flushIfNecessary(HibernateAccessor.java:390)

    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:420)

    ... 32 more
================================================================================
```

In the database, there is no ORA-015555 and ORA-22924 appearing. We increased undo_retention parameter to 8hrs and still got the problems.

Is there anyone who met this problem before and any solution for it?

Comment: What Oracle version are you using?

Comment: Actually, I dont think this issue is related to Oracle version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are trying to read too much LOBs at a time.
If so - then

1. Try to redefine WHAT exacly LOBs to read (probable cause is select * from table_with_many_lobs. Remove that and your problem is solved.)
2. Try to increase retention area size(read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams090.htm) )
3. Try to resize default percentage of storage used for keeping this retention data per column. Like

   ALTER TABLE YOUR_LOB_TABLE MODIFY LOB (LOB_COLUMN_NAME) ( PCTVERSION 50 );

for example.
Hope this helps )

Answer (score 0):

Here is very good page on this issue:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21188547

> Oracle uses rollback segments to store the data that is changed in a
>   transaction. This data is used to restore the original data if a
>   rollback occurs in the transaction.
>
> Also, the data in the rollback segment is used to guarantee
>   read-consistency. That is, that a query always sees the same data even
>   though it might be modified in the middle of the query.
>
> The ORA-01555 occurs if a rollback segment runs out of space.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.